# Serial devices over TCP/IP

Tags: tcp, serial-port, usb, driver, ethernet

This post is to ask for ideas of how to get access the USB devices that are connected to the second PC. I mean that both PC's are in LAN and I would like to see all devices that are connected to the second PC on my first computer like pendrives, printers etc. Any advice will be certainly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any remote desktop client like teamviewer.

Comment: Thank you for your response,but this solution is not exactly what I want to do. I would like to see devices as they are pluged to te first pc, not inside the application

Comment: Then you may write system service (daemons) that talk to other PC. Take a look at usbip project to get an initial idea.